# Libgdx Array Iterator

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm new to libgdx and I was wondering if anyone could anyone explain what an array iterator is, and also how are it's methods used?

```
ArrayIterator<Image> iterator = new ArrayIterator<Image>();//takes in array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `LibGdx` arrays are designed to work as `List` mean you can have resizable array which can grow at run time.

[From Docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html)

> A resizable, ordered or unordered array of objects. If unordered, this
>   class avoids a memory copy when removing elements (the last element is
>   moved to the removed element's position).

[Array.ArrayIterator](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.ArrayIterator.html) : is a `static` inner class to follow the `Iterator` pattern.

`Array` are created like this in `LibGdx`

```
Array<Image> imgs = new Array<Image>();
```

so in order to provide a smooth travel technique iterator patterns are widely used to work with `foreach` loop to traverse the array

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){ Image img = iterator.next();}
```

Benefits of Iterator pattern

- Allow polymorphic statement like `Animal` reference can be used to traverse array of Childs like `Cat` or `Dog`
- Because of iterator pattern , one can traverse any type of collection data (which stored data and support iterator )

Reference:

[**Iterator pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)